# AWS Costing API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I am currently trying to identify the API that handles the reporting for AWS Instances.
[image: Console Report]

I am looking for how the total hours and cost can be identified for all of the instances or just one instance ?

I looked at the XHR Tab and identified 2 API's  that get it

[image: Cost and Usage API]

But i think there should be some way to get this data from AWS-SDK.

Any help would be appreciated . Thanks

Comment: Have you checked the price list api already? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/price-changes.html

Answer (score 1):

You will need to turn on the [Detailed Billing Report](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/billing-reports.html). This will then send billing information to Amazon S3.

The billing files show every specific charge incurred by your account, broken down by resource, tag (needs configuration), region, etc.

Please note that this level of detail is only available *after* you have activated Detailed Billing Reports. You can only obtain high-level information prior to this time.

Answer (score 0):

Most features in the AWS console are directly or indirectly accessing the same documented, exposed APIs that are accessed by the SDKs and CLI.

Most, but not all.

Some features, particularly reporting and graphing-type features -- like these billing/cost reports -- are console-only features.  CloudWatch graphs and CloudFront graphs and reports are other examples that come to mind.  There is no access provided to these other than what's provided in the console.

In each case, the raw underlying data is generally accessible through the documented APIs, but not necessarily the data in its aggregated form as presented on the screen or for download -- you'd need to do your own analysis/aggregation/summary, etc.